# ExtJS: Cross domain issue. CORS parameter it is

Tags: javascript, extjs

**Here is example code:**

```
launch: function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://domain:8090/mailSender/getList',
        method: 'GET',
        cors: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        useDefaultXhrHeader: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
```

I get cross domain error in developer console, what is problem in my code?

Comment: Please post outputs and make sure people can reproduce error

Comment: Is your server cors enabled

Comment: I run the server with the command - sencha app watch. What server uses i don't know. With a similar problem i came cross with angular

Comment: sorry for the confusion, what I mean to be the server is http://domain:8090. when you send the response you have to set some cors related headers and it would be nice to share error message which you currently facing

Comment: I get in chrome console is "Cross-domain error" the rest of the error in the Russian language. And I pointed in the headers of the request is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

Comment: This is log from developer console - A request from an external source is blocked: a single-source policy prohibits reading a remote resource on http: // localhost: 8090 / mailSender / getList? _dc = 1532350988440. (Reason: CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing).

Comment: And also in developer console i see error, but in netword response on my request have 200 code and i can see json from host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the cause. It's necessary, on server-side allow a cross-domain request.
Become application sends options request and in response from the server receives headers (i suppose it's Access-Control-Allow-Origin) which allow application sends to get a request if headers equal request's origin

Answer (score 0):

Latest browsers have security feature built in to disable CORS. You need to restart the browser with CORS enabled.